# JS: Datatables multiple line message

Tags: javascript, datatables

Hello there guys I am looking for a js code where I can add multiple line of message when exporting to PDF

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var printCounter = 0;

// Append a caption to the table before the DataTables initialisation
$('#example1').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy',
        {
            extend: 'pdf',
            footer:true,
            message:'this is line1',
            title: 'This is title',
            orientation: 'landscape',
            messageTop: 'The information in this table is copyright to Sirius Cybernetics Corp.',


        },
        {
            extend: 'pdf',

            messageBottom: null
        },
        {
            extend: 'print',
            messageTop: function () {
                printCounter++;

                if ( printCounter === 1 ) {
                    return 'This is the first time you have printed this document.';
                }
                else {
                    return 'You have printed this document '+printCounter+' times';
                }
            },
            messageBottom: null
        }
    ]
} );
```

} );

I want to know how can I add more `message:` in the pdf file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here https://datatables.net/reference/button/pdf 
`message:` is deprecated. Use `messageBottom:` or `messageTop:`.

Multiple lines are easy. Just use `\r\n` like in

```
messageBottom: function() {
    return '\r\n this is the first line preceeded by an empty line' +
           '\r\n this is the second line' +
           '\r\n \r\n this is the third line preceeded by an empty line';
}
```

Comment: you are welcome. In case you have more questions regarding Data Tables in the future: They have a great forum with quite a few very competent people responding to pretty much all questions you might have.